# I want to animate a floated element when another floated element appear

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the folowing code :

```
.floated {
    Position: relative;
    Float: left;
    Width: 100%;
    Transition: top 500ms linear;
}

.div1 {
    display: none;
}

.div2 {
  display: relative;
}
```

Iwant the second floated element to be animated when i set the first element display to relative. It doesnt work with transition.

Comment: There is no such display value as `display: relative;` .. Do you mean `display: block;` or `position: relative;`?

Comment: Post the relevant markup as well

Comment: Also, I recommend you use lowercase for the property names

Comment: Thank you guys i solved the problem